# WP81 Univeral App - authentication_ui_failed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, adal

I'm having issues with an WP81 Universal App, only after it has been signed & published to Windows Intune. On first login & install of the app, the WebAuthenticationBroker / ADAL package crashes with the authentication_ui_failed error, after signing in successfully with the authentication provider.

One possible resolution I saw was to make sure the Enterprise Authentication & Shared User Certificates capabilities are checked in the app manifest. Are those capabilities required to use the ADAL package, specifically for the phone?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you publish your application with a different name than the one you used in the Visual Studio project? If yes, your identifier will be different - changing the value you should use as redirect_uri and causing the handover with the WAB to fail. You can look up the URI after publication following the instructions in http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/sso/